# Scope error inspite of declaring the vairable

Tags: c++, scope

i am getting a scope error of a variable even though i have declared it. Below is the code

// file.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

struct node {
    int data;
    node *next;
}

void find(node *, int );

int main()
{
   node *head = new node();
   find(head,3);
}

void find(node *curPtr, int node) 
{
  node *refPtr,*mainPtr;

}
```

g++ -g file.cpp

error: ‘refPtr’ was not declared in this scope
   error: ‘mainPtr’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void find(node *curPtr, int node)  // you have one variable calls node 
//                          ^^^^   // which is same name as struct type.
{
  node *refPtr,*mainPtr;

}
```

change it to

```
void find(node *curPtr, int value)
```

Also, you missed `;` after define `struct node`